# Deleting everything between two string matches in a file

Tags: regex, linux, string, bash, shell

I got this text in file.txt:

```
Osmun.Prez@mail.com:c7lB2m6b@3.a.a:tt_webid_v2=6990226111024612869; tt_webid=6990226111024612869; tt_csrf_token=VD5Nb_TQFH4RKhoJeSe2nzLB; R6kq3TV7=AHkh4PB6AQAA3LIS90nWf2ss0Q7ZTCQjUat4axctvhQY68DdUEz92RwpmVSX|1|0|e9d6917c2fe555827dcf5ee916ba9778079ab2a9; ttwid=1%7CAFodeNF0iZM2fyy-ZeiZ6HTpZoG_MSx6SmXHgGVQ-V4%7C1627538859%7C59ca1e4a56f9f537b55e655a6dabff88e44eb48502b164ed6b4199f5a5263cb0; passport_csrf_token_default=6f7653c3ce946a6ce5444723fb0c509b; passport_csrf_token=6f7653c3ce946a6ce5444723fb0c509b; sid_guard=0483b7d37f4e4bd20ab3046e29724798%7C1627538893%7C5184000%7CMon%2C+27-Sep-2021+06%3A08%3A13+GMT; uid_tt=27b52febe6222486b9f6b6a90ef4ffeace5ea25c09d29a1583be5a1ecf760996; uid_tt_ss=27b52febe6222486b9f6b6a90ef4ffeace5ea25c09d29a1583be5a1ecf760996; sid_tt=0483b7d37f4e4bd20ab3046e29724798; sessionid=0483b7d37f4e4bd20ab3046e29724798; sessionid_ss=0483b7d37f4e4bd20ab3046e29724798; store-idc=maliva; store-country-code=us; odin_tt=294845c8f7711db177f7c549a9f44edb1555031b27a2a485df809cd92c4e544ac0772bf462df5b7a100f6e488c45303cd62df3b6b950f0842520cd887850137b035d990f29cc8b752765e594560c977f; cmpl_token=AgQQAPNSF-RMpbE89z5HYF0_-2PcrxjXf4fZYP5_ZA
```

How can I delete everything from the `string` inside ( first & only instance ) from   `:tt_` to `_ZA` in file.txt keeping only `Osmun.Prez@mail.com:c7lB2m6b@3.a.a` using `bash linux`?
Thank you

Comment: It's a good idea to tell us what you have tried so far to solve your own problem.

Answer (score 3):

Something like:

```
sed -i "s/:tt_.*//" file.txt
```

if you want to edit the file in place. If not, remove the `-i` switch.
The *sed* command means: replace (`s`), in each line of `file.txt`, all the chars (`.*`) starting by the pattern `:tt_` with an empty string (`//`).

Or the command:

```
sed -i "s/:tt_.*_ZA//" file.txt
```

which is more adherent to what you ask for, but returns the same output.

Comment: This would leave the initial trailing :

Comment: io.popen("sed -i 's/:tt_.*//' file.txt")
this worked for me! thank u so much!

Answer (score 2):

Use pattern substitution:

```
i=$(cat file.txt)
echo "${i/:tt*_ZA}"
```

Comment: You can also use `cut -d: -f1-2 file.txt`.  In order of least power: builtin > cut > sed > awk > perl >? nodejs/python/ruby.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the general requirement is to remove everything after the 2nd `:` ...

Sample data:

```
$ cat file.txt
Osmun.Prez@mail.com:c7lB2m6b@3.a.a:tt_webid_v ... to end of line
some.one@home.com:B52_m6b@9_az.more.stuff:delete from here ... to end of line
```

One `sed` idea:

```
$ sed -En 's/^([^:]*:[^:]*).*$/\1/p' file.txt
Osmun.Prez@mail.com:c7lB2m6b@3.a.a
some.one@home.com:B52_m6b@9_az.more.stuff
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"}{print $1,$2}'
```

Using `:` as the delimiter, it is easy to extract the columns before `:tt`

Answer (score 1):

This deletes all chars from ":tt_" to the last "_ZA", inclusive, in file.txt

```
Mac_3.2.57$cat file.txt | sed 's/\(\)[:]tt.*_ZA\(.*\)/\1\2/'
Osmun.Prez@mail.com:c7lB2m6b@3.a.a
Mac_3.2.57$
```

Answer (score 1):

Or if it is always the first 2 values which are separated by colon (as per you example)

cat file.txt | cut -f1,2 -d’:’